# How to set up output to certain specifications

Tags: lua, lua-table

I figured out the main concept of my code which reads in a file and sets it to a key then reads in another file and displays the info based on that file. How do I add line 1, line 2. line 3 and so on in front of the output?  As well as add `------------` above and below each new line.

```
-- see if the file exists
function file_exists(file)
  local f = io.open("data.txt", "rb")
  if f then f:close() end
  return f ~= nil
end

-- get all lines from a file, returns an empty
-- list/table if the file does not exist
function lines_from(file)
  if not file_exists(file) then return {} end
  lines = {}
  for line in io.lines("data.txt") do
    first_word = string.match(line, "%a+") -- word
    lines[first_word] = line
    lines[#lines + 1] = lin
  end
  return lines

end

local lines = lines_from(file)

function key_file(file)
    if not file_exists(file) then return {} end
    keys = {}
    for line in io.lines("keys.txt") do
      key = string.match(line, "%a+")
      table.insert(keys, key)
    end
    return keys
end

local lines = lines_from("data.txt")
local keys = key_file("keys.txt")

for _, key in ipairs(keys) do
    print(lines[key])

end
```

Comment: I highly recommend you to add some input you have, output you expect and problems you are facing.

Comment: @CorDell dude, would you please run your code a single time befor you ask how to improve formatting of your output? If I'm not mistaken your code won't output anything. You have several errors or useless lines in your code

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer this in a more general way as your code is not working atm.

You can simply add print commands in the for loop that prints the lines. Or you alter the texts by in some way. See Lua reference documentation for string manipulation and concat operator `..`

```
local numLine = 0
for _, key in pairs(keys) do 
  numLine = numLine + 1
  print("Line " .. numLine .. ": " .. lines[key])
  print("----------")

end
```